# How can I support RTL text with Pixi.js BitmapText?

Tags: javascript, text, pixi.js

Does anyone know of a way to support **RTL** languages (like Arabic/Hebrew.. written RightToLeft) in Pixi.js when using **BitmapText** object ?

We can have many labels in our application so falling back to old Text object would be hard on performance..
Is there some plugin / other library that can help us here ?

currently all the text is reversed there..

Comment: some examples would be helpful.
must you use pixi.js (specifically for rtl)?
do you mean text nodes?  if so, convert to `span` and add `dir="rtl"`?